# Grand Tour Algorithm

Tags: puzzle, hamiltonian-path, path-connected

Below puzzle is known as GrandTour or RoundTrip. The purpose is to connect all dots  and create a cycle. As you can see some paths are already predefined. I know how to generate a Hamiltonian path or cycle within nxn grid. But how about those predefined paths? How can I find the minimum paths (lets say clue) that would result in a unique Hamiltonian path or cycle? What type of algorithm should I look for? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Simply look for nodes that have only two directions for edges to go. The corner nodes are the obvious ones, but also for example the fourth node on the bottom row. Once you draw those edges, and eliminate any moves that would create small loops, you will find more nodes with only two possible directions for its edges to go.